# Prolog every ith element in sublist

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to copy every ith element from a list to a sublist with *just* one ternary predicate sublist(Element, List1, List2) and built-in length and append?
I know, with 4-element auxiliary predicates, it becomes rather trivial, but it isn't what I need.
Can anybody suggest a strategy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with some builtins a declarative solution is really easy:

```
sublist(Element, List1, List2) :-
    findall(E, (nth1(I, List1, E), 0 is I mod Element), List2).
```

while explicitly iterating:

```
sublist(Element, List1, List2) :-
    (   N is Element-1,
        length(T, N),
        append(T, [E|R], List1)
    ->  sublist(Element, R, ListR),
        List2 = [E|ListR]
    ;   List2 = []
    ).
```

where you can see the how to use Boris' suggestion

Comment: findall/3 without any errors and declarative don't got together.

Comment: About the arrow, ( Condition -> WhenTrue ; WhenFalse ). I don't get the other question

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lentgth/2` with the first argument a variable and the second an integer, to create a list of not instantiated variables, like this:

```
?- length(L, 4).
L = [_G936, _G939, _G942, _G945].
```

If you now use `append/3` with this list as the first argument, and a variable as the second, it will split the list in your third argument:

```
?- length(A, 4), append(A, B, [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]).
A = [a, b, c, d],
B = [e, f, g, h].
```

So if you want say the 5th element of a list, you could take the head of the second argument:

```
?- length(A, 4), append(A, [Fifth|Rest], [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]).
A = [a, b, c, d],
Fifth = e,
Rest = [f, g, h].
```

This is not a solution but a valid strategy:

```
every_ith(I, In, [X|Ys]) :-
    N is I - 1,
    length(Prefix, N),
    append(Prefix, [X|Xs], In),
    every_ith(I, Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: If I understand this code correctly, it just seeks and element with a given number in the list. What I needed, though, is to copy *every* ith element to the list. Like this: sublist([1,2,3,4], 2, X). X = [2,4]. Does this code help? Element search could be done easier. Am I missing something?

Comment: You asked for a strategy, not a solution. Look at the edit for a bigger hint.